# Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio en python-3.x, apenas estoy comenzando a aprender este lenguaje

Tags: python-3.x

Escribir una función capaz de ingresar valores enteros y verificar si están dentro de un rango especificado.

La función debe:

- Aceptar tres argumentos: una entrada, un límite inferior aceptable y un límite superior aceptable.
- Si el usuario ingresa una cadena que no es un valor entero, la función debe emitir el mensaje Error: 
  entrada incorrecta, y solicitará al usuario que ingrese el valor nuevamente.
- Si el usuario ingresa un número que está fuera del rango especificado, la función debe emitir el mensaje 
  Error: el valor no está dentro del rango permitido (min..max) y solicitará al usuario que ingrese el 
  valor nuevamente.
- Si el valor de entrada es válido, será regresado como resultado.

Me tengo que basar en este código:

```
  def readint(prompt, min, max):

  # tu codigo aqui
  #

  v = readint("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: ", -10, 10)

  print("El numero es:", v)
```

He buscado y no he encontrado algo para guiarme y poder resolver mi ejercicio.
Hay que usar excepciones.

Comment: Considera editar y mostrar una descripción breve del problema presentado en el título de tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy un experto en python pero podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
def checkNum(promt, high, low):
    if promt <= high and promt >= low:
        print(promt) # devolver el resultado
        return True # Para detener el bucle
    else:
        print('Error: el valor no está dentro del rango permitido ({min}..{max})'.format(min=low,max=high))


def readInt(message):
    while True:
        try:
            num = input(message)

            return int(num) # si el valor no es un número acá ocurrirá un error
        except:
            print('Error: entrada incorrecta')


while True:
    high = readInt('Ingrese el límite superior: ')
    low  = readInt('Ingrese el límite inferior: ')
    num  = readInt('Ingrese el número: ')

    if checkNum(num, high, low):
        break
```

La función `readInt` crea un bucle que no se romperá hasta que el usuario ingrese un valor numérico válido, y luego la función `checkNum` verifica que el número esté en el rango

Comment: Gracias, pero lo veo muy complejo, osea la funcion checkNum no la he visto asi, no puedo emplearla, solo puedo emplear excepciones , raise, assert, bucles y estructuras condicionales y un poco de funciones, supongo que esos conocimientos son los que debo aplicar pero no se como funciona readInt, por eso perdido

Comment: las excepciones las estarías aplicando en readInt, este método lo que hace es crear un bucle que se va a repetir hasta que algo la rompa, cuando el usuario ingresa un número inválido la función tira un error antes que el bucle se rompa, por lo que se va a repetir. En este caso es "return" quien rompe el bucle

Comment: con lo de checkNum, es simplemente un if y else

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve el mismo problema y despues de leer, asi lo pude resolver. Espero que te ayude.

```
def readint(prompt, min, max):

    try:
        prompt = int(input())
        if prompt < min or prompt > max:
            print("Error: el valor no está dentro del rango permitido " + str(min) + " hasta " + str(max))
            return readint(print("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: " , end=''), -10, 10)
     
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: entrada incorrecta")
        return readint(print("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: " , end=''), -10, 10) 
    
    else:
        return prompt


v = readint(print("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: " , end=''), -10, 10)

print("El numero es:", v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi de esta manera.

```
def readint(prompt, min, max):
    try:
        num = int(input(prompt))
        assert num >= min and num <= max
        return num
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: entrada incorrecta")
        return readint(prompt, min, max)
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error: el valor no está dentro del rango permitido (-10..10)")
        return readint(prompt, min, max)
  


v = readint("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: ", -10, 10)

print("El numero es:", v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duré varias horas para poder hacer esto:

```
def readint(prompt, min, max):
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            assert num in range (-10,10)
            return num
            #break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Error: entrada incorrecta")
        except AssertionError:
            print ("Error: el valor no está dentro del rango permitido","(",min,"..",max,")")

v = readint("Ingresa un numero de -10 a 10: ", -10, 10)

print("El numero es:", v)
```

Comment: `assert num in range (-10,10)` debería ser `assert num in range (min,max)`

Comment: No uses `assert` cuando un simple `if` basta y sobra.